# Tapestry5-JQuery Dialog Button Events not firing

Tags: jquery-ui, tapestry

I've made and application that uses Tapestry5-JQuery with JQuery UI enabled. I've created a page with a jquery dialog defined like this:

```
<t:form>
    <t:jquery.dialoglink t:dialog="dlgUrl">Show Dialog</t:jquery.dialoglink>

    <t:jquery.dialog t:clientId="dlgUrl" params="dlgUrlParams">
    <table class="dlgContent">
        <tr>
            <td><t:label for="urlName" class="dlgLabel" /></td>
            <td><t:textfield t:id="urlName" value="name" class="dlgComponent" label="Name:" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><t:label for="url" class="dlgLabel" /></td>
            <td><t:textfield t:id="url" value="url" class="dlgComponent" label="Url:" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="dlgBtnAlign">
        <t:submit class="ui-button ui-widget" value="Ok" t:id="dlgUrlOk"/>
    </div>
    </t:jquery.dialog>
</t:form>
```

The page associated java class is this:

```
public class DialogTestPage {
public JSONObject getDlgUrlParams() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("title", "URL");
    jsonObject.put("modal", "true");
    jsonObject.put("dialogClass", "dlgFileAdjust");
    return jsonObject;
}

@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.SELECTED, component = "dlgUrlOk")
void onClickDlgUrlOk() {
    //Run code after clicking ok
}

void onSuccess(){
    //Run code after form submit
}}
```

When I run the application, button "Ok" does not fire SELECTED Event, and neither onSuccess handler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The DialogLink does not fire any event, the DialogAjaxLink does (EventConstants.ACTION)! The DialogAjaxLink also lets you update a zone.

```
<t:jquery.dialogajaxlink t:dialog="dlgUrl" t:zone="myZone">show dialog</t:jquery.dialogajaxlink>
```

http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsjquerydialog

If you want the success event to be fired you need to submit the form. Either by using a submit button or if you prefer links you can use the LinkSubmit component:
http://tapestry5-jquery.com/core/docslinksubmit

Comment: My problem is not related with showing the dialog with dialog link. My problem is that buttons inside dialog tags do not fire events. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, my bad. The problem is that you can't wrap the dialog in a form. The plugin moves the dialog-container to the bottom of you DOM, so the submit button is actually not inside of the form anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Putting form tags inside t:jquery.dialog solved the problem.